# How to host a Django project on a hostinger VPS?

Tags: django, apache, websocket, celery, vps

I have a Django project. I want to host it on a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). I saw a few VPS services and liked the [Hostinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostinger) VPS. I want to host it to that VPS.

But the problem is, I am using Django [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html). I am also using **Django channels (WebSocket)**. It means, you know, I'm using [ASGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Server_Gateway_Interface).
And I want to use an [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) server with it.

Can I know how to deploy this project on a VPS?

Answer (score 0):

I already deployed a similar project.

You can run Django in ASGI mode using [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) with normal deployment steps, like Apache configuration and redirect...